ダメなんじゃないのかしら? What does it mean here?

鍛えてるのがもてないんじゃなくて、筋肉のために排他的になるのがダメなんじゃないのかしら。……特に南君なんてハマりだすと面倒そうだし？

A character complains he's unpopular because of his muscles and another adds this
How am I suppose to take ダメなんじゃないのかしらhere exactly?
I get

鍛えてるのがもてないんじゃなくて

"You are not unpopular because of your muscles"
and

筋肉のために排他的になるのが

For the sake of your muscles you become exclusionary §
But what does ダメなんじゃないのかしらmean?

There are similar constructions before and after the じゃなくて. Let's parse it like this:

[鍛えてるのAがもてない]んBじゃなくて[筋肉のために排他的になるのAがダメ]なんBだ。
(A = nominalizer; B = explanatory-no)
It's not that [working out makes you unpopular], but it's that [becoming exclusionary for the sake of your muscles is bad (=makes you unpopular)].

Lastly, replace だ with じゃないのかしら, and you get this:

鍛えてるのがもてないんじゃなくて、筋肉のために排他的になるのがダメなんじゃないのかしら。
It's not that working out makes you unpopular, but it's that becoming exclusionary for the sake of your muscles is bad, isn't it?

